# Sorting by substring in sqlite (Date descending)

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am trying to sort my objects by date, descending. The dates are on the following format: dd-MM-yyyy. How can i sort this with substring?

Edit: I currently have

```
 "order by substr(Date, 7, 4),substr(Date, 4, 2), substr(Date, 1, 2) DESC";
```

Which, according to documentation for substr, should do the trick.

The problem is that 1-12-2014 and 2-12-2015 appears between 10-1-2014 and 9-1-2014, like this:

```
10-1-2014
1-12-2014
2-12-2015
9-1-2014
```

Which should appear like this

```
2-12-2015
1-12-2014
10-1-2014
9-1-2014
```

Comment: don't store dates as text if you want to compare them, if you do, you should probably use the builtin date and time functions: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: If you don't understand this line, then you are trying to code using  copy/paste.  This is not a successful strategy.  Why don't you read the documentation for `SUBSTR`, learn what it does, then figure out the line of code?  It's not very hard.

Comment: By the way, @zapl is right.  Storing dates as strings is a bad idea. Dates should only be turned into strings is if you need to format them to show to the user.  Never store or calculate dates with strings.

Comment: @Simon Thank you for two good answers. I read the documentation and think i got it now. It still doesn't work 100%. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @themanwithballs : If you must store your dates as strings then use `yyyy-MM-dd` format. It can be sorted alphanumerically (descending or ascending).

Comment: Your dates are *not* in the `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Comment: @CL. Thanks for being helpful as always... These dates are saved with simpledateformat, dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: `dd` or `MM` would zero-pad the field.

Comment: Answers belong into an answer, not into the question.

Answer (score 2):

**It's solved now, I had to make sure all my dates was on this form: 01-01-2010 (instead of 1-1-2010) and use this line**

```
 "order by substr(Date, 7, 4) DESC,substr(Date, 4, 2) DESC, substr(Date, 1, 2) DESC";
```